# Passing UserID through a ViewBag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to save the Identities UserID in a create action.

Controller GET request is as follows:

```
// GET: Owners/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.RegUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    return View();
}
```

View is as follows:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RegUserID, new { @value = ViewBag.RegUser })
```

Controller POST request is as follows:

```
// POST: Owners/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "OwnerID,OwnerName,ContactName,PhysicalAddress1,PhysicalAddress2,PhysicalCity,PhysicalState,PhysicalCountry,PhysicalPostCode,PostalAddress1,PostalAddress2,PostalCity,PostalState,PostalCountry,PostalPostCode,Phone,Mobile,Fax,Email,RegUserID")] Owner owner)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Owners.Add(owner);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(owner);
}
```

However when the record is saved the RegUserID is null.

If I break on the @Html Helper were the value is assigned to model.RegUserID I can see the UserID in a view:

```
ViewBag.RegUser "7318611e-7e2e-4ee2-9c7b-51b20f0806d8"  dynamic {string}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you do this as opposed to setting the model value in the controller and passing the model to the view (which you should be doing anyway)

Comment: show your ViewModel `Owner` class and rendered html from `@Html.HiddenFor` helper please.

Comment: Also suggest you get rid of that ridiculous `[Bind(Include="..")]` attribute. By default all properties are bound, and if you don't want all properties use `[Bind(Exclude="..")]` or better, use a view model.

Comment: The [Bind... was added when creating the project using database first. I'm new to asp.net and MVC so know of no reason to remove it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have removed the bind completely. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion do not add the hidden field at all. Inside `[HttpPost] Create`  you can access it same way you access it in `[HttpGet] Create`.

```
// GET: Owners/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

// remove RegUserID from Bind Include
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "OwnerID,OwnerName,ContactName,PhysicalAddress1,PhysicalAddress2,PhysicalCity,PhysicalState,PhysicalCountry,PhysicalPostCode,PostalAddress1,PostalAddress2,PostalCity,PostalState,PostalCountry,PostalPostCode,Phone,Mobile,Fax,Email")] Owner owner)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        owner.RegUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        db.Owners.Add(owner);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(owner);
}
```

Like this client can not change that `RegUserID` field.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just create a empty Owner object and send in the get method instead of passing it in ViewBag like so:

```
// GET: Owners/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    Owner owner = new Owner();
    owner.RegUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    return View(owner);
}
```

View is as follows:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RegUserID)
```

Comment: If I do this do I need to change the view or the POST request?

Comment: Not much, it would rather be simpler i.e. just use Model.RegUser. And also I don't know why you had to mention Bind in POST method. Normally MVC will bind your model object.

Comment: I tried this and it worked however the Answer below was cleaner.

Comment: That's ok, whichever helps you most. I am just curious, you showed that you wanted to pass UserID into GET method but your selected answer does not pass it. What's the actual scene?

Comment: I am attaching an Identities User to one of two tables (Owner or Service Company depending on their selection when registering) which holds much more information about them and is linked to other tables. The question only asked about passing the UserID into the GET method because I am learning this stuff and didn't know better :-). Fortunately you guys are very generous with your advice and helping me understand. Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You cant able to assign a value for a strongly typed helper through the HTML helper.

Note: You have to assign the value to you property and then use it as a hidden field. Example given in below.

in your view create a code like below.

```
@{
    model.RegUserID = ViewBag.RegUser;
}
```

Then create a hidden field like below.

```
@{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RegUserID)
}
```